# How can I extract the content between this two page breaks using JSDOM Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, scrape, jsdom

[html image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05lFU.png)Using JsDom how can I extract the content between page breaks? Want to get all the content between...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to get content between tags, for example:

```js
const dom = new JSDOM(``, {
  url: "https://example.org/",
  referrer: "https://example.com/",
  contentType: "text/html",
  includeNodeLocations: true,
  storageQuota: 10000000
});

var bodyhtml = dom.window.document.body.innerHTML;

const regexp = /<span epub:type="pagebreak" .+><\/span>(.*)<p>.+<\/span>/gms;
var content = bodyhtml.matchAll(regexp);
console.log([...content]);
```